# METRO 4 UI: Helper Class to Make Button Stacked?

Tags: web-frontend, metro-ui-css

How do you make a button (just regular button) stacked in Metro 4 UI? Do I miss a helper class for this? I don't seem to find it in Buttons doc page.

Answer (score 0):

d-block is enough; it doesn't seem to irritate the appearance.